# Sampling from distribution using MATLAB / statistical packages like R

Tags: distributions, sampling

I am trying to read Latent Dirichlet Allocation model for Topic modeling. But I am not able to understand how they sample values from a distribution, draw a distribution from a process. In particular drawing from Dirichlet distribution / process. I want to understand all these sampling using MATLAB / R. Please suggest some book/references where I can read the theory part as well as implementation using MATLAB / R. I have very basic knowledge of probability / statistics.

I want to learn from the basics of sampling and its implementation then move to LDA topic modeling.

Comment: regarding sampling: the wikipedia article on dirichlet describes how to sample from a dirichlet in two ways with pretty good detail and pseudocode (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#Random_variate_generation)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i got your request, but i've found the article that might be useful for you.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/topicmodels/vignettes/topicmodels.pdf

Also u could investigate lda package doc to get some examples and description of each method.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lda/lda.pdf